# Install Forefront Threat Management Gateway on Domain controller

Tags: domain-controller, tmg

I have a problem on installing Forefront Threat Management Gateway on Domain Controller. After googling about this, I found that only TMG SP1 can be installed on a DC, but I do not have Forefront SP1.

So I decide this:

1. Install TMG
2. Install Domain Controller
3. Upgrade TMG to SP1

Is this correct?

Also, I got an error about SQL Server during the TMG installation.  Is it better to install SQL Server 2008 R2 by myself?

Comment: Which Forefront product specifically are you trying to install on the DC?  Forefront is the name for [an entire suite of products](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/forefront/ee175814.aspx) which each have their own specific functionality.

Comment: @jscott , I updated my question

Comment: Are you installing on a *read only* domain controller? That is all that is supported with Forefront TMG SP1: http://blogs.technet.com/b/isablog/archive/2010/06/24/forefront-tmg-service-pack-1-now-available.aspx